# How to do bulk insertion in cosmosdb using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-cosmosdb

How to do a bulk insertion in cosmos DB using node.js?

- Is there any library available to make a bulk insertion in cosmos DB?

Comment: why is this question closed?/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no bulk support directly with the node.js SDK but there is [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-js/blob/master/samples/BulkUpdateWithSproc.ts) that uses stored procedure for updates. Can modify to do inserts instead.

hope this is helpful.

Comment: were u able to get this working? i am really not getting on how to invoke this.